# Control font-size so that it fills container as much as possible

Tags: javascript, css, font-size

Im building a treemap visualization, something like this:

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Icicle/example2.html

and I was wondering if there was any way to make that the font-size big as possible to that it fills out the container as much as possible.

This is probably not doable only with CSS, but I wonder if JS wizards have figured out a way to do this.

This is my layout: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4TyP/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used when I needed the same functionality: https://github.com/michikono/boxfit

:)

Answer (score 0):

[slabText](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't this plugin working with WIDTH? I'd need HEIGHT actually?